# Problema con slots y signals en python

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación con señales y slots en python el problema es que al momento de emitir la señal no funciona el método.

Me puede explicar cómo funcionan los slots y signl en oython porque ya me confundí

¿por qué no se ejecuta mi método run?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel,QApplication,QWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread,QRunnable,QObject,pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot
import sys
import time 


class Worker(QWidget,QRunnable):
    iniciar = pyqtSignal()
    label=0
    def __init__(self,label,parent=None):
        print ("iniciando hilos")
        self.label=label
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.iniciar.emit()
    
    def run(self):
        for _x in range (0,10):
            self.label.setText(self.label.text()+ "X")
            
            time.sleep(0.5)

class hilos(QWidget):
     def __init__(self,parent=None):
        
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ventana=QWidget(self)
        self.ventana.setGeometry( 10,10,800,200)
        self.label = QLabel("Valor de x-->")
        self.layout= QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.ventana.setLayout(self.layout)
     
     def ejecutar(self):
        worker=Worker(self.label)
        thread=QThread()
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        
        worker.iniciar.connect(lambda:self.cambio(  ))
        thread.start( )
     @pyqtSlot( )
     def cambio(self):
        self.label.setText("WOW")
        time.sleep(4)

app=QApplication([   ] )
instancia=hilos()
instancia.ejecutar( )
instancia.show( )
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool,QThread , QRunnable, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot import sys import time`
Esta es la clase wrapper le añadi una señal llamada finished que segun yo deberia de emitirla

```
class Wrapper(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished=pyqtSignal(int)
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
```

```
class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self._text = text
        self._wrapper = Wrapper()
        self.started = self._wrapper.started
        self.textChanged = self._wrapper.textChanged
        self.finished=self._wrapper.finished
    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text
    def run(self):
        print(str(QThread.currentThread().objectName()))
        #me refiero a como puedo obtener ese nombre ya que el metodo objectName de la clase QThread no funciona o que esta pasando?
        if QThread.currentThread().objectName()=="HILO_1" and QThread.currentThread().isFinished()==False:
            time.sleep(3)
            self.started.emit()
            for x in range(0, 10):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.textChanged.emit("{} {}".format(self.text, x))
        elif QThread.currentThread().objectName()=="HILO_2" and QThead.currentThread().isFinished()==False:
            time.sleep(3)
            self.started.emit()
            for x in range(0, 20):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.textChanged.emit("{} {}".format(self.text, x))         
        else:
            time.sleep(3)
            self.started.emit()
            for x in range(0, 30):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.textChanged.emit("{} {}".format(self.text, x))
        self.finished.emit(1)
```

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel("Valor de x-->")
        self.label2= QLabel("Valor de y-->")
        self.label3= QLabel("Valor de z-->")
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(self.label2)
        lay.addWidget(self.label3)
    def ejecutar(self):
        hilo_1=[   ]
        worker=[   ]
        nombres_hilos=["HILO_1","HILO_2","HILO_3"]
        worker.append(Worker(self.label.text()))
        worker.append(Worker(self.label2.text()))
        worker.append(Worker(self.label3.text()))
        for x in range (0,3):
            if self.label.text( )== "Valor de x-->":
               worker[x].textChanged.connect(self.label.setText)
            elif self.label2.text( )== "Valor de y-->":             worker[x].textChanged.connect(self.label2.setText)              
            elif self.label2.text(  )== "Valor de z-->":
             
worker[x].textChanged.connect(self.label3.setText)
            worker[x].finished.connect(self.cambio)
            hilo_1.append(QThreadPool.globalInstance())
            #aqui es donde lo asigno pero no se a que objeto lo esto asignando realmente si al hilo o al QThreadPool con el metodo setObjectName si la asignacion es al hilo entonces que esta pasando en el metodo run pero si la asignacion es al QThreadPool como puedo asignarlo al hilo?
            hilo_1[x].setObjectName(nombres_hilos[x])
            hilo_1[x].start(worker[x])
    @pyqtSlot()
    def cambio(self,hilo):
        hilo.quit()
```

```
app = QApplication([])
instancia = Widget()
instancia.ejecutar()
instancia.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

La logica del AP tiene muchos errores ya que combina muchos conceptos diferentes.

Qt es una librería que ofrece muchas metodologías y clases para implementar el multi-threading como son:

- *Override* el metodo `run` de un QThread.
- Implementar un worker(QObject) que viva en un QThread.
- Usar QThreadPool con un QRunnable.
- El módulo QtConcurrent.

De acuerdo al código y lo que señala el OP esta convinando la logica del QRunnable con un QThread y eso es incorrecto.

Si se va a usar un QRunnable entonces tendras que usar un QThreadPool que internamente creara los QThread y hara que el metodo run se ejecute en otro hilo.

Por otro lado PyQt no permite la multiple herencia(solo hay algunos casos especificos esta permitido) por lo que no tiene sentido heredar de QObject y QRunnable.

Ademas no debes interactuar con la GUI desde otro hilo ya que esos objetos no son *thread-safe* por lo que Qt los prohibe, en vez de ello debes usar las señales que si son *thread-safe*.

Los QRunnable no son QObject por lo que no pueden tener señales asi que una posible solucion es crear un QObject con esas señales y crear un *wrapper* para que sean accedidos en el QRunnable.

Por último, en tu caso no se invoca al *callable*(el método cambio en tu caso) porque la conexión se da despues de la emisión.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sys
import time


class Wrapper(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self._text = text

        self._wrapper = Wrapper()
        self.started = self._wrapper.started
        self.textChanged = self._wrapper.textChanged

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    def run(self):
        self.started.emit()
        for x in range(0, 10):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.textChanged.emit("{} {}".format(self.text, x))


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel("Valor de x-->")

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

    def ejecutar(self):
        worker = Worker(self.label.text())
        worker.started.connect(self.cambio)
        worker.textChanged.connect(self.label.setText)
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cambio(self):
        self.label.setText("WOW")


app = QApplication([])
instancia = Widget()
instancia.ejecutar()
instancia.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Entonces según por qué tengo entendido gracias a ti un QThreadPool crea los QThread automáticamente y el método run se genera en otro hilo

Comment: Además para que sirve el método GlobalInstance(. )

Comment: 1) *el método run se genera en otro hilo*, no se invoca en el otro hilo. 2) globalInstance() retorna el QThreadPool creado por defecto

Comment: Disculpa por la molestia amigo va a decir que te molesto pero como podría agregar otro hilo en tu código además de sabes que hilo es ?

Comment: @AldairMartinez 1) Crea otro worker e invoca a `QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(new_worker)`, 2) tu última pregunta es confusa por lo que no te entiendo, 3) por favor revisa [ask] y pasa el [tour]

Comment: me refería a como puedo saber puedo asignar el nombre de un hilo está el método setObjectName () pero para obtener ese nombre desde el método run como le hago

Comment: @AldairMartinez A quien asignas el "objectName"?

Comment: me refiero al codigo de la segunda respuesta que subi

Comment: @AldairMartinez 1) Eso no es una respuesta ... ya que no responde a nada, 2) QThreadPool no es un hilo sino una manejador de hilos. 3) ¿por que es necesario identificar a los QThread? Si se usa el paradigma QThreadPool+QRunnable entonces no se puede acceder a los QThreads internos. 4) No te seguire ayudando si no lee las guias que te he pasado ya que no cumples con las reglas del sitio